# Error:how to fix the swift error type to my server

Tags: python, swift

I get a confused error.
Its about swift data type.
there is my network demo:

```
func initRequst(HttpType: httpType,content:String,dic:Dictionary<String,Any>){
        let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic, options: .prettyPrinted)
        print(data)
        switch HttpType {
        case .post:
            url = URL.init(string: "http://localhost:5000/" + content)
            req = NSMutableURLRequest.init(url: url!)
            req?.httpMethod = "POST"
            req?.httpBody = data
        case .get:
            url = URL.init(string: "http://localhost:5000/" + content)
            req = NSMutableURLRequest.init(url: url!)
            req?.httpBody = data
            req?.httpMethod = "GET"
        }
    }
```

And there is my flask server have received error and demo:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

@app.route('/userLogin',methods=["GET"])
    def userLogin():
        get_username = request.json['username']
        get_password = request.json['password']
        return jsonify({"uerId":databasePort.checkUserInformation(get_username,get_password)})
```

it seems that swift data sending type have not be identified.How to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: i have already fix it.The issue is that request.json[....]cant receive my json data,so i finally use the request.form instead.its works.

Comment: I don't think that you have really fixed the problem, you've worked around it instead. The proper solution would be to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` before sending the request in Swift. Then Flask will attempt to decode it and assign it to the request's `json` attribute:

```
req.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Flask will set `request.json` only if the incoming request sets the content type to json, otherwise it will assume form encoded data which it will assign to `request.form`.

Comment: Thanks! that explains why  i use the curl test my server is works well,but not